# Amazon: SSLHandshakeException happening intermittently

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

This is a difficult problem for me. The following shows the portion of the code that throws the exception when I try doing an Amazon search:

```
AWSECommerceServiceLocator locator = new AWSECommerceServiceLocator(fooConfig);
locator.setAWSECommerceServicePortEndpointAddress(SourceCountry.USA.getPortAddress());
//throws exception
AWSECommerceServicePortType type = locator.getAWSECommerceServicePort();
```

Heres the exception:

> NativeException: bc.exceptions.FatalException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

The weird thing is that this happens intermittently. At times, everything works perfectly. Anybody have any ideas? At this point, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several root causes:

- Outdated java installation which doesn't contain a valid root certificate for some of the Amazon servers
- Invalid server-side certificate that is not trusted by any valid issuer

To debug to the console from the client side, add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to the command line.  The page on [Debugging SSL/TLS connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) may provide insight into the underlying error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is intermittent though. Your root causes don't account for this fact.

Comment: Assuming that Amazon has more than one server satisfying requests via a randomized load balancer, the problem could be on the server size.  Trapping the debug and error when it occurs could determine if a particular server has a problem.